Apache Flink - restarting job on the same JobManager after its restart
Is it possible to do following scenario without HA setup on Apache Flink?

start job
restart job manager
job manager restarts previously started job based on checkpoint

I was trying to set various properties but every time after a restart of JM, nothing happens basically.
Can it be done without HA setup then ? I am using 1.19 version at this point.
From answers i've found looks like not, and we have to have HA cluster with leader election, and then simply new leader should restart the job.
Wanted to confirm this.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you have a savepoint or a retained checkpoint, I believe you should be able to restart the JM and then restart the job from the saved state.
